# From database to application scope

Tags: java, mysql, list, servlets

my question is involving database and application scope. I am currently running an web application that stores user info(for login), item info and purchase info. The way I am currently doing storing the data is by putting them in a List. I am thinking of storing the data to a database (mysql) and replace the lists. In thinking about it, i thought of whether it would make sense to store data in the database, but also store it in the Lists. Basically, i would be adding to the List via the database. Would it make sense to do this?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not save the entire list into the field but each element in the list should be a separate row in the table. This is object-oriented design and it would be good practice to do so.

To achieve this, you need to have a one-to-many mapping for the user table to the purchase table. One user can make multiple purchases but each purchase can only be tied to one user. Therefore, your purchase table should contain a foreign key which is the ID for your user table.

[image]

For example, table A should be the list of all your users. Table B should contain all your purchases. We can see that Doug has made 3 purchases, (PA,WV and DE) while Bob has made 2 purchases (TN and NC).